formula for number of blocks with mortar in a distance
I want to work out a formula to use in basic code for the following scenarios.
d = distance
bw = block width
mw = mortar width
b = number of blocks

how many blocks b (or fraction thereof) is there in d if there is mortar between every block but there might or might not be mortar at the end of the last block.
scenarios using the formula b = d / (bw + mw)
d = 480
bw = 230
mw = 10

b would equal 2, this is correct.
d = 470
bw = 230
mw = 10

b would equal 1.958, this is incorrect, it should still equal 2 as i only need to know the number of blocks.
d = 595
bw = 230
mw = 10

b would equal 2.479, this is incorrect, it should equal 2.5 as i only need to know the number of blocks not including the fractional part of the mortar.

Looks to me like you need integer division, and possibly the modulus operator, but you need to tag a language since the syntax can vary.

I am using ArchiCAD gdl (I wil add the tag) but not many people us it. Happy for visual basic as I can convert over.

How can it equal 2.5 if you need to know the number of blocks? Does the .5 mean half a block? If so, why not .479 of a block?

I am ok if the answer has a decimal. It doesn't need to be whole blocks. But 230 + 10 +230 + 10 + 115 = 595 and had exactly 2.5 blocks, not 2.479 as my formula produces.

I voted to reopen because it is definitely about programming - the OP is using the GDL programming language, which is tagged, and said that a solution in the Basic programming language would also be acceptable. There is an algorithm involved in calculating the solution and very plainly this is about programming.

As it's closed, I can't post an answer, but here you can find a solution in Basic: https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/1fxf. Click the "Run" button to see the proof.

What do you want the answer to be for d = 235? Is it one brick plus 5mm of mortar (so b = 1), or should it be always bricks at each end? In the latter case, it would be 10mm of mortar in the middle and 112.5mm of brick at each side (so b = 0.978).

thanks @k314159. if d=235 I would want it to equal 1.

@k314159, missed your jdoodle previously. Yes, your code works for the solution i need, thx.

# integer division to calculate whole blocks
whole_blocks = d // (bw + mw)

# deduct whole blocks from distance
remaining_space = d - whole_blocks * (bw + mw)

# divide remaining space by block width to get partial blocks
# if greater than 1, reset to 1 (the rest will be mortar)
# then add to whole blocks
final_blocks = whole_blocks + min(remaining_space / bw, 1)


I don't think it's possible for d - whole_blocks * (bw + mw) to be negative, so you should be able to simplify your code.

@k314159 Agreed, that was a hold over from previous (incorrect) code. When I changed it, I should have change that too.

Thanks @MatBailie. However if d=235, bw=230 and mw=10. Answer would be 1.022 as it calculates the decimal of the mortar which I don't want. This should be = 1.

@mark Are you using integer division for step one? This answer should give 0 for whole blocks, 235 for remaining space, and 1 for final blocks.

@Mark I've tested Mat's code and it seems to work the way you want it. This answer uses Python syntax, which you can translate to GDL. The // is integer division, i.e. it rounds the result down to the nearest integer. See it running at https://onecompiler.com/python/42qyjagty

@k314159, my bad, I did realise it was integar division but incorrectly calculated manually, I think this solution is good, thankyou both.

Use next amended formula: b = int ((d + bw) / (bw + mw)).
In int(X), the int function rounds down to the greatest whole number less than or equal to X.
With d = 480; bw = 230; mw = 10
                      Before INT()   After INT()

(  0 + 230) / (230 + 10) = 0

( 10 + 230) / (230 + 10) = 1       \
( 20 + 230) / (230 + 10) = 1.042   |
( 30 + 230) / (230 + 10) = 1.083   |
...                                |  1 brick for d = [10,240]
(220 + 230) / (230 + 10) = 1.875   |
(230 + 230) / (230 + 10) = 1.917   |
(240 + 230) / (230 + 10) = 1.958   /

(250 + 230) / (230 + 10) = 2       \
(260 + 230) / (230 + 10) = 2.042   |
(270 + 230) / (230 + 10) = 2.083   |
...                                |  2 bricks for d = [250,480]
(460 + 230) / (230 + 10) = 2.875   |
(470 + 230) / (230 + 10) = 2.917   |
(480 + 230) / (230 + 10) = 2.958   /

(490 + 230) / (230 + 10) = 3       \
(500 + 230) / (230 + 10) = 3.042   |
(510 + 230) / (230 + 10) = 3.083   |
...                                |
(595 + 230) / (230 + 10) = 3.438   |  3 bricks for d = [490,720]
...                                |
(700 + 230) / (230 + 10) = 3.875   |
(710 + 230) / (230 + 10) = 3.917   |
(720 + 230) / (230 + 10) = 3.958   /

To work out the length of the last partial brick:
PartialBrick = d - ((b - 1) * (bw + mw))

eg. For a distance of 595 (b=3) and we get 595 - ((3 - 1) * (230 + 10)) which is just 115 or half a brick. So while consuming 3 bricks, you'll effectively be using 2.5 bricks.

The op wants fractions of a block. They just want to exclude the effect of the mortar on the final block. So d=7 b=2 m=1 should yield 2.5 but they're currently getting 2.333

Thanks @Sep Roland. Got me on the right path.  I replaced code PartialBrick = d - ((b - 1) * (bw + mw))  with code if d - (b * (bw + mw)) > 0 then final_bricks = b + (d - (b * (bw + mw))) / bw' else final_bricks = b 
